# Login Page usigng mvc in .net

Tags: .net

I want to make a login page using mvc architecture in .net. I am using Visual studio 2010 and Sql server2008. So please suggest me what should i make first model,view or controller ? and  in which sequence i shoud make them. Login data is verified by fetching from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just create a mvc project and start from there. as it usually will already come with an Account Logon controller.

if you want a more comprehensive sample you can always [check the nerddinner example](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

Comment: sorry sir link you have sent does not has any qualitiful information for me. Please help me sir.

Comment: melaos have give you all the info that u need. Simply create a new ASP MVC project... the login page is included by default and you can see the code. What else do you need?

Comment: yup, you can just download the accompanying pdf guide and read through it alongside the code, this should give you a clear enough example of what to do. and if you're stuck then just come back to SO for answers :)